# Pivot Table VBA code not displaying any result

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I want to automate the pivot table process in my department for my colleagues that have trouble with Excel.

I found the code below online. It worked for me the last time, however, when I try to apply the same macro to another set of data (45000 rows vs. 4800 rows) it doesn't give me any result, just a blank page.

I read online that some versions of Excel cannot handle Data sets that have more than 65000 lines. I am currently using Excel 2016 at the office so I don't see what  the problem is...

Can you please help me resolve the problem?

```
Dim PTableSA as PivotTable
Dim PCacheSA as PivotCache
Dim PRangeSA as Range
Dim PSheetSA as Worksheet
Dim DSheetSA as Worksheet
Dim LR_SA as Long
Dim LC_SA as Long

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts=False
Application.ScreenUpdating=False
Worksheets("TCD Sanctions").Delete
Worksheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "TCD Sanctions"

Set PSheetSA = Worksheets("TCD Sanctions")
Set DSheetSA = Worksheets("Sanctions")

LR_SA = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LC_SA = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set PRangeSA = DSheetSA.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LR_SA, LC_SA)

Set PCacheSA = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRangeSA).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheetSA.Cells(2, 2),TableName:="TCD_Sanctions")
'I think the problem starts here when excel coumdn't create Pivot Table

Set PTableSA = PCacheSA.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheetSA.Range("A1"),TableName:="TCD_Sanctions) 

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TCD_Sanctions").PivotFields("Aggregate BU")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TCD_Sanctions").PivotFields("Alert status")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 2
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TCD_Sanctions").PivotFields("Year month")
.Orientation = xlColumnField
.Position = 1
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TCD_Sanctions").PivotFields("Entity type")
.Orientation = xlPageField
.Position = 1
End With

'Defining pivot table format
Active.Sheet.PivotTables("TCD_Sanctions").ShowTableStyleRowStripes = True
Active.Sheet.PivotTables("TCD_Sanctions").TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium9"

'Show in Tabular form
PSheet.PivotTables("TCD_Sanctions").RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TCD_Sanctions").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "TCD_Sanctions").PivotFields("Alert ID"), "Count of Alert ID", xlCount
End Sub
```

Comment: Get rid of the `On Error Resume Next` - that's hiding an error.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, the error starts here 'Set PCacheSA = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRangeSA).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheetSA.Cells(2, 2),TableName:="TCD_Sanctions")'

Comment: "Error 13, type mismatch" was indicated

Comment: Split the `PivotCache` and `PivotTable` creation in two separate lines. Then you'll need to use a `String` for the `SourceData` argument - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcaches.create where it says "When passing a Range object, we recommend that you either use a string to specify the workbook, worksheet, and cell range, or set up a named range and pass the name as a string. Passing a Range object may cause "type mismatch" errors unexpectedly."